# "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built" concept in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm currently migrating a lot of maven-jenkins-jobs to gitlab-ci.

In these jenkins-jobs my team heavily relies on the "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built"-trigger, because we have many interdependent build-artifacts (jars and wars). 
Like this, it is ensured that if `lib-SNAPSHOT.jar` is changed and rebuilt, also `dependent-SNAPSHOT.war` is rebuilt and potential compatibility problems show up immediately.

I think I can achieve the same behavior if I manually set up triggers between the artifact-builds, like described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/README.html#triggering-a-pipeline):

> Now, whenever a new tag is pushed on project A, the job will [...] be executed, triggering a rebuild of project B

However, that will be very difficult to maintain. Is there a better/more elegant/less maintainance effort/more magical solution to achieve this?

Comment: How did you finally solve your issue ? An answer would be very helpful!

Comment: @peter: sorry, but I have never solved it... As a workaround I'd suggest configuring periodic rebuilds on all jobs, so you detect it at least with some delay.

Comment: Thanks for answering! May I ask If you've changed your Maven builds or did you switch back to Jenkins ?